# Custom Gutenberg block saved markup does not update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have been using the Gutenberg-Block https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor. I am having difficulty re-rendering the front end markup after updating it. It will only show the version of the markup in which the plugin was activated and will not update upon resave of the content or unless I deactivate/re-activate the plugin and click recover.

How can I resolve this? Example:

**1. save method**

```
export default function save(props) {
  return (
    <div className="my-custom-class">
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

**2. expected output**

```
<div className="my-custom-class">
 ...
</div>
```

**3. updated save method**

```
export default function save(props) {
  return (
    <div className="my-custom-class">
      <div>New Markup</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**4. expected output**

```
<div className="my-custom-class">
   <div>New Markup</div>
</div>
```

**5. actual output**

```
<div className="my-custom-class">
 ...
</div>
```

My assumption is this markup gets stored in the DB upon creation, but updating the content does not resave the markup.

Comment: Is `<div>New Markup</div>` created from a RichText element in `edit()`? If not, can you please add your `edit()` function and block attributes from block.json?